# De-serializing JSON with Gson on Android without the redundant key

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit2

I am trying to de-serialize a JSON response that looks this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2
  }
}
```

To de-serialize it, I need a class structure more or less like this:

```
class ActualData {
  int a;
  int b;

  // and the usual stuff...
}

class Wrapper {
  ActualData data;
}
```

My question is: Is there any other way in which I can de-serialize this json object without needing a `Wrapper` class and directly parse the `ActualData`.

I am using a third-party API so I cannot make modifications on the server. Also I am using [**retrofit2**](https://github.com/square/retrofit) with [**Gson**](https://github.com/google/gson).

Comment: What do you mean by duplicate data. The question is not clear.

Comment: See Converter objects http://f2prateek.com/2017/04/21/unwrapping-data-with-retrofit-2/ And https://medium.com/@oldergod/how-i-got-the-best-of-retrofit-2297cb56a40f

Comment: Thanks a lot @cricket_007! The Converter objects worked! and thanks for those links too!